# Workflow to post on Jekyll via Windows

Tags: window, jekyll

I am currently working on a Jekyll blog on Linux. However I'd like to add contributors to this blog who are using Windows and who haven't any skills in programming or using tools like Git etc.

I was wondering what could be the best process/pratice to enable them to post on the blog?

Installing them the entire environment and writing a script maybe?

Could it cause any issues due to the OS?

Any suggestions or advices are welcome :)

Comment: Where is your blog hosted?

Comment: I see two easy ways here. 1. You could upload your blog to GitHub and host it with GitHub Pages and allow each user to contribute to the project. So, they could work from github.com itself, by adding new .md files to the _posts folder directly. You can add a robots.txt if you want to prevent bots from finding the site. 2. Install  Sublime Text to the contributors' PCs and add a plugin to preview markdown, so they would have an idea how the post would render. And give them a guide though writing in markdown. The best way, though, would be setting up Jekyll to their PCs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think installing git, and pushing content to your repo is hard task for any non-tech guy.

1:  Little tough way

1. Use team viewer and help your partner to setup git.
2. [Allowed access to your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).
3. Teach them, about frontmatter, and some jekyll commands.

2: Simple and smooth way.

Just get doc files dirctly from partner, which contain only content, nothing else, and convert yourself into markdown with manual frontmatter.

3: Create your own dashboard.

You can create your own dashoard like WordPress, where your partner can add categories, tags, title, meta description etc things, that can convert into frontmatter automatically. For that, you need to build yourself. (I find out that kind of generator [here](http://gridster.digitalmind.ch/documentation/#generator), but look's like he deleted, you can find it, by visiting him, old deleted commits).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I ended up using Wordpress as the interface to it and creating a plugin to marry the systems up.

I figured I'd share it so feel free to have a look:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp2jekyll/